# htaccess request as 'folder'

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i ran into a problem, im trying to map url to folder(virtual one),
so, im trying instead of `http://site.eu/controlpanel.php?username=Username&do=services`
map it as `http://site.eu/cp/user/services`

Im using the following code
`RewriteRule ^cp/([^/]+)/([^/]+) /controlpanel.php?username=$1&do=$2 [L,QSA,NC]`

All fine, except two things, if im trying to access

```
http://site.eu/cp/user/
```

it gives me 404 Error (why?)
Also, if im trying to access anything further than

```
http://site.eu/cp/user/services/
```

Like

```
http://site.eu/cp/user/services/ServiceID/
```

or

```
http://site.eu/cp/user/services/ServiceID/Action
```

It gives me same error.

In php file, im using this construction

```
<?php
switch($_REQUEST['do'])
{
   case 'services':
    some code to display page;
   break;

}
?>
```

I dont know how to make this pages, after /cp/user/services/.../... available to users.

Help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following structure instead:

```
RewriteRule ^cp/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ /controlpanel.php?username=$1&path=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

So, if you use the URL:

`http://site.eu/cp/user/services/ServiceID/Action`

...you'll be sent to:

`http://site.eu/controlpanel.php?username=user&path=services/ServiceID/Action`

Then, in your PHP file:

```
<?php
$path = ($_REQUEST['path']) ? explode('/', strtolower($_REQUEST['path'])) : array();

if (!empty($path)) { // A path is established; find the page.

    if ($path[0] === 'services') {
        if (!empty($path[1])) { // Visitor is at '/cp/user/services'.
            // ...
        }
        else if (ctype_digit($path[1])) { // Visitor is at '/cp/user/services/[ServiceId]'.
            // ...
        }
        // ...
    }

}
else { // No path exists. Visitor is at '/cp/user'.
    // ...
}
?>
```

Comment: the problem here, if user opens /cp/user/services/ - than it thinks that path[1] is set, but if /cp/users/services - than it opens services page

Comment: Also, service id - auto generated service number, so i cant match it to any variable or string

Comment: Solved problem by using `is_numeric($path[1])` instead of `isset($path[1])`

Comment: This should work better if you change the first condition for `$path[1]` to `if (!empty($path[1]))`. For the second condition, you should use [`ctype_digit($path[1])`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) instead of `is_numeric()`, because `is_numeric()` will allow decimal / float values, but `ctype_digit()` will only allow integers. See my edits to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the second parameter optional and match more than a single path node:

```
 RewriteRule ^cp/([^/]+)/(?:(.+)|)$ /controlpanel.php?username=$1&do=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```